# BlackBerry 10 database persistent storage

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry-10

Can anyone tell me how to store data persistently in database ?

I have done one simple app in which I have connected databases with it to store values but whenever I close this application,  the previously stored data gets deleted . I want this data to be stored even if we close the app or it should fetch data whenever we reopen the application .

Can anyone please tell me solution?

Answer (score 2):

Another question on BB10 basics eventually you should consider the documentation given to the ndk. SQLite is available on BB10. 
The documentation can be found here:

https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/core/data_management.html

and the reference can be found here:

https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/core/

You should be able to access a SQLite even through Qt using `QSqlDatabase::addDatabase()`

Comment: PS: If you solve a question yourself write your solution also, so others do not have to ask again :)

Comment: the data management link has moved: https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/data_management.html